# Unify linux script for C/C++ and PHP applications

Tags: php, c++, linux

I have a Linux script that will be used to start/stop applications written in both C/C++ and PHP. With C/C++ I have no problem, but to understand the PHP applications my systems needs **php-cgi**, and my PHP files need to have the file extension '***.php***' to be understood (while C/C++ are perfectly understood without an extension).

So if I want to run applications in C/C++ I just write:

```
"$APPNAMEBIN" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But when I have applications in PHP I need to write

```
php-cgi "$APPNAMEBIN" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To make it easier for the user and to unify the rules I want to have an script that simply has one line to run the applications, no matter what programming language was used. And this way be able to omit the file extension too.

So I was thinking if there is a way to put it at the beginning of the script like for example:

```
#! /path/php-cgi
```

So my system understand that PHP applications need to run with that.

I am very new in this, so I am not sure if what I am asking for is possible or if there is another way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it? That is what I do with PHP scripts that I run on the command line. You also want to set them to executable. Then, you can use `myphpscript.php` to run them.

Comment: Try it; that should work.

Comment: Ok, I just tested it. I created a basic script to call a php file and a php program that just writes a word into a text file...but it doesn't seem to work. 

If I use 'php-cgi' in the script to start the application it works fine, but when I add the '#! path/php-cgi' and remove the php file extension from my test program it does not create the text file..

Comment: OK, it works :D My mistake. All ok :)

Thank you.